# Read PDF table data using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

```
General ledger 1234567
|10/01/2020 | Total date 10/01/2020 | 1,500.00 | 1,500.00 |
|10/02/2020 | Total date 10/02/2020 |          | 3,780.00 |
|10/03/2020 | Total date 10/03/2020 | 700.00   |          |
|10/04/2020 | Total date 10/04/2020 | 60.00    |          |
```

I am using PDF Box to extract PDF Table data to get the amount of credit and debit.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file.getInputStream());
        document.getClass();
        if (!document.isEncrypted()) 
        {
            PDFTextStripper Stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            Stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            Stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(true);
            String pdfFileInText = Stripper.getText(document);
            String linex[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
            for (String line:linex) 
            {
                if(line.contains("General ledger "))
                {
                    String gl = line.replace("General ledger ", "").trim();
                    String g = gl.substring(0, Math.min(gl.length(),7));
                    w = g.trim();
                }
                if(line.contains("Total date "))
                {
                    String po = line.replace("Total date ", "");
                    String txts = po.replace(",", "").trim();
                    String[] datahere = txts.split("\\s");
                    String date = datahere[0];
                    String otherdata = datahere[1];
                    String first_amount = datahere[2];
                    String second_amount = datahere[3];
                    if(first_amount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        first_amount = "0.00";
                    }
                    if(second_amount.isEmpty())
                    {
                        second_amount = "0.00";
                    }
                    write.println("<p>"+date+"---"+first_amount+"--"+second_amount+"</p>");
                }
            }
            document.close();
        }
```

It's working when both two amount has a value, except when second amount is empty till next line.

Here's the example of PDF table data wherein I am going to get the data and calculate the difference of two amounts. When Debit continuously empty, it will display java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3.

Comment: These two lines are suspicious: `if(first_amount.equals(""))` and `if(second_amount.equals(""))`.  Q: Have you stepped through the debugger?  Are you sure if second amount is "empty" the value is *ALWAYS* `""`?  Who knows, maybe it's " " or 10 spaces or something else entirely?  Q: What exactly is `datahere[3]`? when it's "empty"?

Comment: actually ive tried it so many times, it will get the value if it is exist and display. but when it is empty, it will display 0.00

Comment: Please add your input or share your PDF. Or tell what's in `datahere`, and how many elements. You can output it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datahere))`.

Comment: So split() doesn't return 4 array elements. Your code is unsafe because it makes this assumption. Extracting tables from PDFs is notoriously difficult, unless you know exactly the positions.