# PDFBox parse PDF table data with blank fields as well

Tags: java, pdfbox

**Need:** Read table data in PDF document with blank column data as well

**Issue:** If a specific column has no data, it skips that column instead of putting a blank space  while parsing the data & output on console. So in the output I do not know if it is Buy Qty or Sell Qty

**Research:**

1. Issue is similar to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585801/read-pdf-table-data-using-pdfbox) but there is no solution there.
2. I also checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751329/pdfbox-skipping-text) on a similar issue, but does not help with mine

**Query:** Any pointers on what setting will help me extract data with blank space as desired

**Note:** I cannot share the actual PDF document as it contains sensitive data.

**Table Data in PDF document:**

| Order No | Time | Buy Qty | Sell Qty | Price | Settled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 09:23:45 | 250 |  | 354.4 |  |
| 1234589 | 13:38:10 | 300 |  | 400 |  |
| 1234677 | 14:28:15 |  | 100 | 980 |  |
| 1234722 | 15:45:50 |  | 265 | 770 |  |

**Output at Present:**

```
"1234567 09:23:45 250 354.4"

"1234589 13:38:10 300 400"

"1234677 14:28:15 100 980"

"1234722 15:45:50 265 770"
```

**Desired Output:** (with blanks for empty fields)

```
"1234567 09:23:45 250   354.4  "

"1234589 13:38:10 300   400  "

"1234677 14:28:15    100 980  "

"1234722 15:45:50    265 770  "
```

Code:

```
String pdfText = "";
try {
       File file =  new File("C:\\data.pdf");
       PDDocument pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(file);
       // Tried the below option as well, but does not help
       pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
       pdfText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDocument);
       pdDocument.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    
String[] arrayPDF = pdfText.split("\\r?\\n");
for (String data : arrayPDF) {
                System.out.println(data);
            }
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983991/1729265) help?

Comment: @mkl indeed it helps. With a few modifications, was able to get it. Although need to do some string manipulations from the extracted text in the format I need. Can you add your response as answer, so I can mark the same as answered. Thanks

Comment: Well, link-only answers are not really liked here. But we could close your question as duplicate of that other question.